# Delphi OpenH264 decode

Tags: delphi, openh264

i'm using the cisco OpenH264 codec in coding and decoding process , the coding stage works very well and i can read my encoded H.264 file correctly , the issue is with my decoding process and mainly the conversion from I420 to ARGB , please can any one helps to fix this .

Here's my Decoding function ( from the OpenH264 wrapper DLL ) :

```
/*
* [ IN ]   SourceData : the encoded frame(s)
* [ OUT ] pTargetbuffer : the Target buffer 
* [ OUT ] width
* [ OUT ] height
*/
 {

    int iStride[2];
    init();

         ... the decoding routine : pData contains the YUV 

        if (ret != dsErrorFree) {

            return -1;
        }
        if (!m_sBufferInfo.iBufferStatus) {
            return -2;
        }

    LWidth = m_sBufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iWidth;
    LHeight = m_sBufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iHeight;
    *width = LWidth;
    *height = LHeight;

      iStride[0] = m_sBufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[0];
      iStride[1] = m_sBufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[1];



        return 0;
}
```

and here's my Delphi implementation :

```
Image.Picture.Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
Image.Picture.Bitmap.Width  := 320;
Image.Picture.Bitmap.Height := 240;
    ...
Result:=H264Decoder_decode(FEncodedBuffer,
                            Image.Picture.Bitmap.ScanLine[Image.Picture.Bitmap.Height-1],
                            EncodedBufferSize,LWidth,LHeight);

 if result=0 then Image.Repaint;
```

So many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many thanks , i fixed the issue ; the problem was just i set :

```
Image.Picture.Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
```

But the correct `PixelFormat is the pf32bit`

Comment: your could provide this your complete Delphi version of **OpenH264**? could upload in some repository for example on GitHub or some other place to download? I'm needing very much of this :-)

Comment: i'm working in a project example Delphi + Android (Java) where i want receive real time stream of screen of device like [this model](http://www.dobest.me/blog/2016/06/17/Android%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%AD%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88/), but i want receive on Delphi in a `TImage` like you showed above on question.

Answer (score 0):

The stride size (`int dst_stride_frame`), you give to `H264Decoder_decode()` has to be `width * 3`.

That is, because you want to convert into a 24-Bit RGB image, where one pixel takes 3 Bytes (24bits / 8).

With `width * 2` your converted image will only contain 2/3 of the data, resulting in your image. `width * 4` would come into effect, if you want to convert to 32-Bit RGB.

Comment: so many thanks , if i change `width * 2` into  `width * 3` i get that AV too.